# Powershell remoting issue

Tags: powershell, remoting

I am trying to use powershell remoting from Server A to server B using Enter-PSSession -Computername ServerB. Both servers are in the same domain. Remoting is enabled on server B using Enable-PSRemoting , which has worked fine. I can use Enter-PSSession -computername command from ServerA to other servers fine.

when trying Enter-PSSession -Computername ServerB from SErver A, it gives following error:

```
FullyqualifiedErrorId: CreateRemoteRunSpaceFailed
```

Running winrm get winrm/config on serverB gives following:

```
Listener
    Address = *
    Transport = HTTP
    Port = 5985
    Hostname
    Enabled = true
    URLPrefix = wsman
    CertificateThumbprint
    ListeningOn = 127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.4, ::1, 2002:b40a:1a8b::b40a:1a8b, fe80::100:7f:fffe%12, fe80::200:5efe:180.10.26.139%14, fe80::681a:e480:25fd:e50e%13
```

Firewall on all servers is off.

Any Idea on "FullyqualifiedErrorId: CreateRemoteRunSpaceFailed" error?

thanks 
vb

Comment: http://ilearnedit.wordpress.com/2011/11/29/powershell-remoting-configuration/

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/54417b48-68ae-40ac-a303-74aed4e7e81a/help-with-remoting-powershell-ise

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a matching user account on server B? Have you tried doing:

```
Enter-PSSession -Computername ServerB -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

and setting your domain username/password?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the other server(ServerB) to trusted hosts list in serverA? If  not add it as below:

Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts ServerB

Answer (score 0):

Trusted hosts and local accounts should not be used if the machines are in the same domain and the user has local admin rights.

The machines
Can you ping Server b from server a?

You said you can remote to other machines from Server A can you remote to Server B from other machines?

Has your user account got local admin rights on server B?